# SDL2_Gfx - Linker issue with cygwin

Tags: c++, gcc, cygwin, sdl

I'm struggling to compile SDL_Gfx with cygwin.
The configure script worked without issues.

Here's the last makefile command:

```
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -Dmain=SDL_main -no-undefined -release 1.0 -version-info 0:1:0  -o libSDL2_gfx.la -rpath /usr/local/lib SDL2_framerate.lo SDL2_gfxPrimitives.lo SDL2_imageFilter.lo SDL2_rotozoom.lo  -L/usr/lib -lcygwin -lSDL2main -lSDL2
libtool: link: warning: library `/usr/lib/libSDL2.la' was moved.
```

And here's the linker "warning" message.

```
*** Warning: linker path does not have real file for library -lSDL2main.
*** I have the capability to make that library automatically link in when
*** you link to this library.  But I can only do this if you have a
*** shared version of the library, which you do not appear to have
*** because I did check the linker path looking for a file starting
*** with libSDL2main and none of the candidates passed a file format test
*** using a file magic. Last file checked: /lib/libSDL2main.a
```

If i try to ignore this, I'm getting this error when I try to use the library inside my application:

```
In function `pixel':
/usr/local/lib/SDL2_gfx-1.0.1/SDL2_gfxPrimitives.c:75: undefined reference  to `SDL_RenderDrawPoint'
/usr/local/lib/SDL2_gfx-1.0.1/SDL2_gfxPrimitives.c:75:(.text+0x11): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `SDL_RenderDrawPoint'
```

UPDATE: I tried to switch compiler to use mingw64 instead of cywin. I'm having a similar issue, I think this is related to libtool since I can compile an external programs with similar c/l flags without issues.

I don't know what I can try I ran out of ideas, please help.
Thank you

Comment: In which library is defined SDL_RenderDrawPoint ?

Comment: /lib/libSDL2main.a is static not shared, for that reason you have the libtool warning. You need to check before why it was not produced as shared. The second error is likely a follow up of the first.

Comment: additional. Have you installed libSDL2-devel package or you built it by yourself ?

Comment: @matzeri I downloaded the SDL2 devel package for mingw64, I did not build it myslef. Meanwhile, as a workaround to this problem, I also found a package for SDL_gfx that was pre-compiled for mingw64. I'm using it since I struggled so much to build it from sources.

Comment: if you mixed cygwin and mingw64 binaries, I have not doubt you struggled